# Alchemy Account Activity webhook not firing for internal transfers

Tags: alchemy, internal-transactions, arbitrum

According to the [webhook docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/address-activity-webhook) when listening for account activity on an address it should include internal transactions. I'm not seeing any though.  For example when i list a NFT for sale on OpenSea with account `A` and then buy it with account `B` I get webhook notifications:

1. A `category: 'external'` event that shows the transfer of ETH from address `B` to the OpenSea smart contract representing the purchase of the NFT
2. A `category: 'token'` event that shows the NFT token transfer from account `A` to account `B` representing transfer of ownership of the token

However I do not ever see the expected `category: 'internal'` event representing the transfer of ETH from the smart contract to account `A`. Alchemy also has a [blog post](https://www.alchemy.com/blog/internal-transactions-notifications) that says this functionality is available.  I'm working on Arbitrum Goerli at the moment but the webhook docs say it is supported there.  What am i missing?